# Embedded mono + app.config

Tags: mono

I have embedded mono in a c++ program and loaded a dll which requires an app.config. I am getting this kind of error, does someone have an idea on how to ship ***.config with an embedded mono ?

The stack trace :

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Error Initializing the configuration system. ---> System.ArgumentException: The 'ExeConfigFilename' argument cannot be null.
  at System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationHost.CheckFileMap (ConfigurationUserLevel level, System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap map) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationHost.InitForConfiguration (System.String& locationSubPath, System.String& configPath, System.String& locationConfigPath, IInternalConfigRoot root, System.Object[] hostInitConfigurationParams) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.C[] hostInitConfigurationParams) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfigurationInternal (ConfigurationUserLevel userLevel, System.Reflection.Assembly calling_assembly, System.String exePath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.get_Configuration () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 onfiguration.InternalConfigurationSystem.InitForConfiguration (System.String& locationConfigPath, System.String& parentConfigPath, System.String& parentLocationConfigPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration..ctor (System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationSystem system, System.String locationSubPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationFactory.Create (System.Type typeConfigHost, System.Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self answer : you can't (as of 2013-04-30). To enable this behaviour, I had to change mono's framework sources mono/mcs/class/corlib/system/appdomain.cs :

```
public AppDomainSetup SetupInformation {
    get {
        return SetupInformationNoCopy; // newline
        //  AppDomainSetup setup = getSetup (); //old
        //  return new AppDomainSetup (setup); //old
    }
}
```